# Windows domain join service account permission

Tags: windows, active-directory

I need an Active Directory service account to join new machines to the domain. I want to give least privilege to this account. Apparently any domain user can join machine to the domain however, there's limited number of times? What permission do I need to assign to the service account?

Comment: At a minimum, you need to grant the account the "Create Computer objects" permission on the OU(s) in question.  I *think* that's all you need, and that the permissions on computer objects you create automatically include the necessary rights to complete the join.  You might get a more informed answer on Server Fault, though, since this isn't really a programming question per se.

Comment: Note that if the account is compromised later on, the machines it joined to the domain may be exposed to some extent.  At a minimum, the rights necessary to join a machine to the domain also allow you to break the machine's connection to the domain, and join another machine in its place.  (Perhaps a second service running with higher privileges whose only job is to clean up the computer accounts after they have been joined?)